# How to make a thread.start() to return a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, threadpool

I am using `requests` in python using which I am firing pool of parallel requests using threads. The requests are processed in another function. I want the cookies for each requests to be returned to the calling threads. But I am getting "**None**" value when I am trying to return the dictionary from the called function. So is there any way to make a thread to return some value?

Since the `Thread()` has arguments like `target` and `args`, does it also have any argument to specify the return type? Here is the part of my code:

`t = []
for k in range(0, rowCount-1):
   t.append(threading.Thread(target = Requester.req, args = (username[k],password[k],url[k])))
   t[k].start()
   t[k].join()`

Comment: Could you post some code, please ?

Comment: I think `Thread.start()` cannot return anything, unless you try to create a child class and override `start()`. Instead, you can make your dictionary global, so it is accessible both for the thread and for the rest of the functions